# Big Knob Studio not showing showing up in list of ouputs in settings

Tags: sound, usb, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I had an older Mackie Big Knob Studio and used it showed up in my list of audio outputs fine. My old unit stopped working and I got a new one. Now this one is not showing up in the list in the settings menu.

Linux info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

If I run `aplay -l` I see it in the output below:

```
card 1: STUDIO [BIG KNOB STUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I changed the USB port and still the same.

**This worked perfectly on Ubuntu before.** Any audio tips would help so I can select it as an output in the settings.

Any help would be great!

Tried restarting pulseaudio and got this error:

```
systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-08-03 22:33:19 EDT; 2min 41s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 9195 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 38269)
     Memory: 8.5M
        CPU: 170ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─9195 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Aug 03 22:33:19 user pulseaudio[9195]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
Aug 03 22:33:19 user pulseaudio[9195]: Failed to find a working profile.
Aug 03 22:33:19 user pulseaudio[9195]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="usb-LOUD_Technologies_Inc._BIG_KNOB_STUDIO-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-LOUD_Technologies_Inc._BIG_KNOB_STUDIO-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
```